# PHP Form Drop Down menu stills blank after I select an item

Tags: php, html

I am executing an form based on PHP on Windows, however after I select an item in the drop down menu, the text does not show up (even though it was selected properly, as I can verify in the database after clicking the insert button).

The form code:

```
<div id="janela_formulario">

    <form action="inserir_transportadoras.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nometransportadora" placeholder="Nome da Transportadora">
        <input type="text" name="endereco" placeholder="Endereço">
        <input type="text" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone">
        <input type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade">
        <select name="estados">
            <?php
                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_estados)) {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $linha["estadoID"];  ?>">
                    <?php echo utf8_encode($linha["nome"]);  ?>
                </option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>                        
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="cep" placeholder="CEP">
        <input type="text" name="cnpj" placeholder="CNPJ">
        <input type="submit" value="inserir">
    </form>
</div>
```

The dropdown menu PHP code:

```
<input type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade">
    <select name="estados">
        <?php
            while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_estados)) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $linha["estadoID"];  ?>">
                <?php echo utf8_encode($linha["nome"]);  ?>
            </option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>                        
    </select>
```

How can I solve it?

[image]

[image: After I select an item in the dropdown menu, it still blanck]

Comment: are you getting selected value visible in selectbox ?

Answer (score 0):

```
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_estados)) {
                echo '<option value="'. $linha["estadoID"] .'"> '.utf8_encode($linha["nome"]).' </option>';
}
```

Use above code instead of while loop

Comment: I have tested your code and I am getting the same error.

Comment: then it is error in your query, please check it in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

test by inspect HTML code. is this estadoID are printing properly if yes then test you are catching (estados) data properly